# #spinner{} element fails two worker when Nginx is the reverse proxy in front of Nitrogen

Tags: ajax, nginx, erlang, load-balancing, nitrogen

I have running my Nitrogen driven application directly however because i want to use Nginx load-balancing magic i found out that the progress notifier of Nitrogen, the Spinner is not showing at all. I followed the example as at [Nitrogen configuration options - bottom of the page](http://nitrogenproject.com/doc/config.html). The example code snippet at the link is shown below.

```
# My config for a site that I only want serving SSL content.

server {
    listen   80;

    server_name www.mysite.com, mysite.com;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/mysite.com.access.log;

# rewrite all requests to be SSL
    rewrite ^(.*) https://$host$1 permanent;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com
    access_log /var/log/nginx/mysite.ssl.access.log;

    ssl on;

    ssl_certificate ssl/mysite/mysite.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key ssl/mysite/mysite.com.key;
    ssl_client_certificate ssl/mysite/ca.crt;

    location / {
    # This installation is running on port 8021, as you can plainly see.
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
}
```

Without Nginx the spinner works fine. I am using Nitrogen over Yaws of release as stated in the RELEASE file `[{release,"nitrogen","2.3.0-beta5","5.10.3",[...,...,...,...],permanent}]`. I do not what I am not doing right.

Comment: Spinner starts with ajax request and stops, when it is finished. Is the actual ajax request working? Is it the same, when you use http and https? Also, check out the nginx access and error logs, when you are trying this out.

Comment: The actual ajax requests are working properly without the spinner spinning.

Comment: There nothing is log files.

Comment: Nothing even in access logs? That is strange. Maybe the request is so fast, that spinner is not needed. I am out of ideas. Maybe someone else will be able to help. Good luck!

Comment: Well the fix was done. It was because of the change to websockets in the release. I pulled a fixed nitrogen.js and it cleared. I realized that it was not caused by Nginx because even without the reverse proxy it didn't spin.